# Why I can't get value from SQL query?

Tags: .net, sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to get result of a SQL query to a variable in PowerShell. Connection to the database seems to be working fine because at the output I get "Online" message.

Can you tell me what can be wrong right here?

Query works normally in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
Param(
         [string] $Server= "WIN-EBQ95HA6M6V\SQLEXPRESS",
         [string] $Database = "myDB",
         [string] $SQLQuery= $("SELECT state_desc FROM sys.databases where name='myDB'"),
         [string] $SqlQueryResult
    )
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;"
    $Connection.Open()

    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
    $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()

    while ($Reader.Read()) {
         $Reader.GetValue($QueryResult)
    }

    $Connection.Close()
    return $QueryResult
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Though the sample is missing function declaration and curly brackets, the actual query works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning your result to an internal `$Reader` variable but then you try to return `$QueryResult` at the end.  You're basically returning the wrong variable.

Also, if you seek to expand your SQL Query down the road to return multiple columns or more than one row, you will likely need to revise your code to build and return an internal dataTable object.

Here's how you could do that, with a snippet from the [mmsSQL PowerShell module](https://github.com/fredbainbridge/mmsSQL/blob/master/Commands/Invoke-mmsSQLCommand.ps1):

```
$SqlReader = $SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

$results = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$keepGoing = $true
while($keepGoing) {
    while($SqlReader.HasRows) {
        $SqlDataTable = New-Object -TypeName "System.Data.DataTable"
        $SqlDataTable.Load($SqlReader)
        $results.Add($SqlDataTable) | Out-Null
    }
    try{
        if(-not $SqlReader.NextResult()){
            $keepGoing = $false
        }
    }
    catch {
        $keepGoing = $false;
    }
}
$SqlReader.Close()
if($results.Count -eq 1){
    $results[0]
}
else{
    $results
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `$QueryResult = $Reader.GetValue($SqlQueryResult)`?